# Magento 2: get product through api using id?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I want to get product information using API call. I have product id of that product is it possible to do that.

Answer (score 13):

To get product information using API call with product id you can use following API with searchCriteria :

GET /V1/products

http://domain.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=5325

```
 {'searchCriteria':{'filterGroups':[{'filters':[{'field':'entity_id','value':"1",'condition_type':'eq'}]}]}}
```

In searchCriteria add filter with product id as above.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define a new API.

So, let's define a new interface:

```
<?php

namespace XXX\Productby\Api;

interface ProductByInterface
{
    /**
     * GET product by its ID
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $id
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    public function getProductById($id);
}
```

The definition is similar to the core API, and it throws the same exception.

Now, let's define a model to implement this:

```
namespace XXX\Productby\Model;

use XXX\Productby\Api\ProductByInterface;

class ProductBy implements ProductByInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getProductById($id)
    {
        return $this->productRepository->getById($id);
    }
}
```

Then, simply use your webapi.xml file to use this method when accessing a given route, adding something like:

```
<route url="/V1/xxx-productbyid/:id" method="GET">
    <service class="XXX\ProductBy\Api\ProductByInterface" method="getProductById"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

and to bind the model to the interface in the di.xml file:

```
<preference for="XXX\Productby\Api\ProductByInterface"
               type="Wow\Productby\Model\ProductBy"/>
```

Now you can access your product through APIs with a simple GET call:

```
GET /V1/xxx-productbyid/12345
```

Source: I had to already do this and even accessing the product with its URL key. Blog article [here](http://lorenzosfarra.com/2017/06/20/magento2-api-get-product-details-by-id-or-url-key/).

Comment: We don't need to define new API in this case, we can re-use the already function. See my answer.

Comment: Lorenzo, can you please explain where should those files to be placed and what should be their names?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look: `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface`

```
public function getById($productId, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false);
```

As we can see, Magento already provides the function to get product by Id. We can re-use it.

Create a new module, declare the new api url:

*app/code/Vendor/CatalogProduct/etc/webapi.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/products/id/:productId" method="GET">
        <service class="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface" method="getById"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="Magento_Catalog::products" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Now, we can get: `http://magesitd.loc/rest/V1/products/id/1`

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean SKU when you say you have product ID?

If so, yes, you can call `https://domain.com/rest/V1/products/:sku` where `:sku` is the product SKU.

You can see a full list of APIs [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html).

Comment: No i have product id not product sku.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the filter

```
http://www.mysite.co/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=entity_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq
```

Use field **`entity_id`** instead of **`id`**

value is Product Id here **`1`**

condition_type is equal to here **`eq`**.