# how we can get product name , image, price and url in magento 2 product factory collection

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.2

How we can get product Name, 
               image, 
               price 
               url

in magento2 product factory collection

Comment: Where are you trying to get in block, controller ? Do you want to get for current product or load by ID?

Comment: actually, I need product information in custom API

Comment: I assume you are trying to load the product by ID, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167075/magento-2-get-product-through-api-using-id this link can be help for you

Comment: I have tried with load by product id but not working. name,url, price are coming but i am not ablet to get product image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the product name, url, price and image by following code:

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

    foreach ($collection as $product){
        echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
        echo 'Price  =  '.$product->getFinalPrice().'<br>';
        echo 'Url  =  '.$product->getProductUrl().'<br>';
        echo 'Image = '.$product->getImage().'<br>';
    }
?>
```

You need to add pub/media/catalog/product before the image url you will in the loop.

If you want this on controller then inject the required class and then use the collection.

If you have product ID then use the below code:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
```

Comment: only image is not coming rest of data is coming.

Comment: Is it coming null or something else?

Comment: Coming as null

https://prnt.sc/kjritn

Comment: Can you try print_r($product) and see if image is coming properly on thumbnail or small_image attributes?

Comment: Here is print data of product

https://prnt.sc/kjrkyf

Comment: Did you add this line: $collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

Comment: Please check here is function : https://prnt.sc/kjrn29

Comment: Wait its wrong as you dont need product collection if you have product ID. I am updating my answer.

Comment: Check my updated  answer.

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding.